# Animate css attributes: from "top" to "bottom"

Tags: jquery

**Update 2**

I figured it out. If anyone have similar problems, see my answer.

**Update**

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HBUAx/

**Post**

I'm working on a few animations with jQuery.
I have 3-4 elements which should slide in from the top. I defined their positions with css:

```
#element-1 {
    top:124px;
    left:0px;
    right:auto;
    bottom:auto;
}

#element-2 {
    top:230px;
    left:670px;
    right:auto;
    bottom:auto;        
}

#element-3 {
    top:auto;
    left:0px;
    right:auto;     
    bottom:100px;
}
```

Then I save their positions initial on pageload, cause i have to manipulate the css value to

```
top: -1000px
```

to hide them and make the "slide in from top" animation possible.

```
var image_margins = [];
$('img').each(function() {
    var obj = $(this),
        id = obj.attr('id'),
        mtop = obj.css('top'),
        mleft = obj.css('left'),
        mright = obj.css('right'),
        mbottom = obj.css('bottom');

    // save alle margins in array
    image_margins[id] = {mtop:mtop,mleft:mleft,mright:mright,mbottom:mbottom};

    // hide all content elements 
    obj.css({'top':'-1000px'});

});
```

When the user clicks the animate button, the elements should slide to their saved positions.
The problem: i can't remove the `top` attribute. Some elements only have bottom margins. I tried to set `top` to `auto` or `''`, but it's always `0px` in DOM inspector. And `bottom` don't work if `top` is set. How can i get rid of the `top` attribute?

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('img').each(function() {
        var image = $(this),
            id = image.attr('id'),
            timeout = 0;

        setTimeout(function() {
            var mtop, mleft, mright, mbottom;
            if (image_margins[id].mtop != 'auto') { mtop = image_margins[id].mtop; } else { mtop = ''; }
            if (image_margins[id].mleft != 'auto') { mleft = image_margins[id].mleft; } else { mleft = ''; }
            if (image_margins[id].mright != 'auto') { mright = image_margins[id].mright; } else { mright = ''; }
            if (image_margins[id].mbottom != 'auto') { mbottom = image_margins[id].mbottom; } else { mbottom = ''; }
            image.animate({'top':mtop,'left':mleft,'right':mright,'bottom':mbottom},500);

        },timeout);
        timeout = timeout + 200;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Please could you supply a working example of the problem, perhaps using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). The question does not include any markup so it is difficult to answer

Comment: For sure: http://jsfiddle.net/HBUAx/ As you see, the red square should animate to the end of the container. But cause of the top:0px it doesn't slide to the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i figured it out.
I have to check if the element have a defined `top` position. If not, i have to hide it with a large `bottom` value.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/gg33z/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(element).css('top', '');
```

This should unset the "top" value.

Comment: OK, can you please post a jsFiddle of your problem?

Comment: For sure: http://jsfiddle.net/HBUAx/ As you see, the red square should animate to the end of the container. But cause of the top:0px it doesn't slide to the bottom